# Symfony - pass custom data from Form Builder to form theme

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I would like to set a special div surrounding a bunch of my fields. For that I want to add something to the form builder that I could detect in my form_theme, and set the div when it's there.

I tried to add

```
->add('field', new myCustomType(), array('inherit_data' => true, "label" => false, "required" => false, 'attr' => array("test" => "aaa")))
```

to the form builder, setting an custom attr, it's actually rendered in the html as an attribute... But I'm unable to detect it in the form theme.

```
{{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}
```

Only gives the widget attributes, and

```
{{ block('row_container_attributes') }}
```

doesn't work. I actually have a hard time finding any source online about what variables are available in the `blocks` of the form theme and how to use them (it was already difficult to know how to call blocks).

I looked for some more information on the official site, [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) mostly but without any success...

Thanks ahead for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put it in your form builder, then you might as well permanently set in your template. If there is some logic required to set the data, then that belongs in your controller anyway, so just put it there to start with.

Controller:

```
public function someAction()
{

    // ....

    return $this->render('some_twig_template.twig.html', array(
        'attr' => array("test" => "aaa")
    );
}
```

Then in your twig template

```
{{ dump(attr) }}
{{ dump(attr.test) }}
```

EDIT:
To render in your template every time, you can set a class on the rendered field directly:

```
{{ form_label(form.field, 'My label', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'js-hidden-row'} }) }}
{{ form_widget(form.field, { 'attr': {'class': 'js-hidden-row'} }) }}
```

Then in my javascript you can hide with some simple jQuery:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-hidden-row').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for helping ! Actually it's not really logic it's more a display thing. I want some div to be hidden by default, with a clickable button to show it... So I wanted to set the attribute in the form builder, on that specific field, so in the form theme when detecting the attribute is there I can set a div with `hide` class and add the button... I guess I could do it in the template itself by defining form fields in their html one after the other and not using `{{ form(form) }}` but I'm surprised there is no simple way to set something like this...

Comment: Makes sense. I would still argue to not put this in the form builder. Since you want to render on that field every time, just put it in your template. I'll modify my answer to show how I do it.

Comment: Thanks, that was the way I started to go to !